# How to store and read user usage data of my application in Android using java?

Tags: java, android, dictionary

I have created a an application for a project - it's very basic... what I would like to do next is see how users are using my application e.g. buttons pressed, which page is viewed the most, for how long etc.

I am new to java and I do not understand how I can implement such thing; I have an idea but do not know whether it is efficient;

I would add a counter for each of the buttons in my app, whenever a button is pressed the counter increases by 1 and so on and so forth;
To see how long a user stays on a page, I could add a timer when the user enters the page, timer starts and stops when user exits.
...

Would something like this is viable and efficient? are there better ways of implementing such algorithm.

Not sure if there are, I searched but couldn't find any, does google offer such service like they do for websites with google analytic.

I am sorry, I've no to show this, as I haven't actually starting doing it. Wanted to get a grasp of it before I do and find out whether it is the correct strategy.

I would really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/v4/

Analytics for android apps maybe its what u are looking for

Answer (score 0):

Start here: http://www.google.com/analytics/mobile/
https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/v4/

You could also go with that you stated already, and add those values to an array. Just note that this will require you to turn on some permissions which might make your app unpalatable for some individuals.

Comment: I am not planning to release, just a personal project for which I am trying to studying behaviour of my app and whether its useful.